# Bash doesn't write history

Tags: bash, macos

i tried to read other similar posts but i couldn't find any solution.
I'm using a Mac with Iterm and as my title my bash doesn't write the history.

here my tests:

```
echo $HISTFILE
/Users/myname/.bash_history

echo $HISTSIZE
100000

echo $HISTFILESIZE
100000

set -o | grep history
history         on

ls -ltr .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 myname staff 0 Jul  1 12:31 .bash_history
```

I tried to delete e create again the .bash_history file without resolve.

if i change from bash to zsh with the command `chsh -s /bin/zsh` it works, but i need to use `/bin/bash`

Please someone can help me?

Comment: `here my tests:` so how are you testing if bash writes to history? The write does not happen each command, are you aware of that?

Comment: To get/force your latest commands into the history file, you might do `history -a`. See `help history`.

Comment: @Roadowl i have tried with `history -a` but nothing. For each command the history keep empty

Answer (score 0):

I saw this article for mac,

Do you have a
`ls -l /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` file
If you do, this seems to setup a HISTFILE and totally ignores any attempt at setting your own HISTFILE

After reading the comments in the `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`, it seems you can set the following variable in your `$HOME/.bash_profile file`:
`SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0`

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 8909 Oct 17  2016 /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`
and disable this behavior so that your own HISTFILE settings will take, or even honor the default bash history file name.

Once I set `SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0` my Terminal bash history behavior started to behave as expected.

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work, i updated my question, i added this test 
if i change from bash to zsh with the command chsh -s /bin/zsh it works, but i need to use /bin/bash

Comment: Maybe the bash_history could be corrupted, you could rename this file temporarily and then log out and in again, and see if a new bash_history was created and then run some commands, and log out and then log in again, and then look at the bash_history file?